# SQLite Exception while attaching database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting following exception while attaching a sqlite database in another sqlite database in Android Application

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error: , while compiling: ATTACH DATABASE /data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases/database AS MASTER
```

Any suggestions what can cause this error.

Thanks,

Comment: Does the database name need to be in quotes?

Comment: the string refers to path of database. So it should not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database name [is an expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html), so it must be quoted:

```
ATTACH DATABASE '/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases/database' AS SomeName
```

And I doubt that the name of your package is actually `PACKAGE_NAME`, or that your database file is actually named `database`.

Comment: Does this actually work? I cannot reference the attached database. For example, `SELECT * FROM SomeName.tableThatExists` fails with a *no such table* error.

Comment: @Phil To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button. But I guess you have [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18489889/11654).