# sqlite4java no such table error by attaching another database

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I'm using sqlite4java to handle with sqlite db. I want now to copy a table from database to dbtest. So I found the code here on stackoverflow. But I get always an error. First of all I open a connection to my new created database and afterwards I attach the other database with the following command:

> ATTACH DATABASE database AS database;

This works fine. dbtest has been opended earliere as new database.
Then I want to copy the tables: Hence, the table is already created and it is the same as in the other database.

> INSERT INTO dbtest.Routing (id, source, destination, metadata, zone_src, zone_dst,cost) SELECT * FROM database.Routing;

But after executing this I get the error:

> com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [1] DB[1] exec() no such table: dbtest.Routing

I tried it also with sqlite Studio and there it is working without any problems, but I cannot attach a database there (this is done automatically). Do I have to use another notation to use two databases?

**EDIT**:
I use now the answer from CL. But this leads to the new issue:

> com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [1] DB[1] exec() no such table: second.Routing

What did I change?

> ATTACH DATABASE database AS second; //new name for the database file and it will be attached as second, because if I use the debug function it says: Database second already in use.

If I use this command I get the error mentioned above.

> INSERT INTO Routing (id, source, destination, metadata, zone_src, zone_dst,cost) SELECT * FROM second.Routing;

Problem solved by using the absolute path for the database file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of attached databases is *not* its file name but whatever you've specified as name in the `AS` clause of the `ATTACH` statement.

Neither is the name of the main database (the database to which the other database was attached) its file name. Its name always is `main`.

To specify the name of a table in your main database, use `main.Routing`, or just `Routing`.

---

Please note that SQLite is perfectly happy with creating a new database if the file does not yet exist, so you have to ensure to give the correct file name to the `ATTACH` statement.
If your database file is not named `database` or if it is not in the current directory, the `second` database will be empty.
It is strongly recommended to always give the complete file path, like this:

```
ATTACH DATABASE '/some/where/whatever.db' AS second;
```